# Having trouble with Translation APIs with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, google-translate, bing

Good evening,

I am fooling around with an app that takes SpeechToText, and then translates into a string of another language. I've messed around with the Bing Translate API(Microsoft Azureus?) and the Google Translate API(free trial.), but both of them giving me the same error.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                String translated = "dis no werk";
                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String textRes = result.get(0);

                GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");

                // Set the Google Translate API key
                // See: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html
                GoogleAPI.setKey("AIzaSyBzi2f7aaeLFiFZaa2QGfM-GR_xReLwpHs");
                try {
                    translated = Translate.DEFAULT.execute(translated, Language.ENGLISH Language.FRENCH);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(translated);
                }catch(Exception e){txtSpeechInput.setText(e.getMessage());}
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
```

That is my main function. I copied this from a [google translate API git](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) because Google's official documentation says very little if anything about using it in Android Studio. Both Bing and Google's API catch the exception with e.getMessage() returning "exception. error retrieving translation: null".

I have added the jar into my lib folder (ProgramFiles\AndroidStudio\lib AND AndroidStudioProjects\GoogleTranslate\app\lib). 
This line is in my \AndroidStudioProjects\GoogleTranslate\app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('lib/google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar')
}
```

However, my other gradle file in \AndroidStudioProjects\GoogleTranslate\build.gradle
has nothing referring to the google translating api. whenever I try adding it in, it starts to give me the error the Gradle can't sync, preventing the entire thing from compiling.

Also, why are there two files called build.gradle?!

I have added `<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to my manifest.xml, although it doesn't seem to do anything.

So yeah, I'm totally stumped. Anyone know what I can do to get these to work?

I suppose I should say, I am currently on the trial for Google's Translate API, and the API key says its valid on the Dev Homepage. Same thing with Azureus.

Slightly unrelated question: I used the book Android for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach to "learn" Android, but frankly, I'd like to start fresh. Any suggestions? I realize this is probably answered all over the place, so I'll probably comb through other posts. Wouldn't hurt to ask here tho :D

Comment: Edit your answer and remove your key now. It will used by anyone.

Comment: Can you post the exact stack trace of the error you are getting when using the Translation API? In case this issue is still happening, you may want to use the Translation API’s [Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) instead, as it does not require the use of any API key when running locally and provides a complete sample on how to translate a text String.